# Asp.net after a long procedure the next operation can't be completed

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, oracle

i have the following code that call a stored procedure and then makes One insert on another table.

The problem is that when the procedure takes few time to complete everything works well, instead,
when the procedure get long time (the session dose not seem to expire ) but the next operaion on the db 
makes the session "inactive"

web.config:

```
    </webServices>
    <trust level="Full" />
    <httpRuntime 
    executionTimeout="90000000" 
    maxRequestLength="2097151" 
    useFullyQualifiedRedirectUrl="false" 
    minFreeThreads="8" 
    minLocalRequestFreeThreads="4" 
    appRequestQueueLimit="1000" 
    enableVersionHeader="true"
    />
```

asp.net page:

```
    OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
            objCmd.Connection = connection;
            objCmd.CommandText = "insertReqSched";
            objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

            if((Session["chkAllSoc"] != null)&&(Session["chkAllSoc"].ToString() == "1"))
            {
                /*
                selezionare tutte le soc di vendita e metterli in una string separati da ,
                */
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select uidaccount FROM ACCOUNT A INNER JOIN ACCOUNTTYPE AT ON A.UIDACCOUNTTYPE = AT.UIDACCOUNTTYPE WHERE ACCOUNTTYPENAME IN ('RETAILER','ELIGIBLE_CLIENT') order by name asc",connection);
                 reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                string socVends = "";
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    socVends = socVends + "" + reader.GetInt32(0) + ",";
                }
                reader.Close();

                OracleParameter socVal = new OracleParameter("socVend",OracleType.VarChar);
                socVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
                socVal.Value= socVends.Remove(socVends.Length - 1);
                objCmd.Parameters.Add(socVal);
            }
            else{
                OracleParameter socVal = new OracleParameter("socVend",OracleType.VarChar);
                socVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
                socVal.Value= ((Session["socVend"] != null) && (Session["socVend"].ToString().Length != 0)) ? Session["socVend"].ToString()  : (object)System.DBNull.Value;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add(socVal);
            }
            if((Session["chkAllPlant"]!= null)&&(Session["chkAllPlant"].ToString() == "1"))
            {
                /*
                selezionare tutti gli impianti e metterli in una stringa separati da ,
                */
                OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select plantcode from plant",connection);
                 reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                string plants = "";
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    plants = plants + reader.GetString(0) + "," ;
                }
                reader.Close();

                OracleParameter plantCode = new OracleParameter("plantCode",OracleType.VarChar);
                plantCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
                plantCode.Value= plants.Remove(plants.Length - 1);
                objCmd.Parameters.Add(plantCode);
            }
            else{
                OracleParameter plantCode = new OracleParameter("plantCode",OracleType.VarChar);
                plantCode.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
                plantCode.Value= ((Session["plantcode"] != null) && (Session["plantcode"].ToString().Length != 0)) ? Session["plantcode"].ToString()  : (object)System.DBNull.Value;
                objCmd.Parameters.Add(plantCode);
            }
            OracleParameter bllingParam = new OracleParameter("billingcy",OracleType.VarChar);
            bllingParam.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
            bllingParam.Value= ((Session["billingcycle"] != null )&&(Session["billingcycle"].ToString().Length != 0)) ? Session["billingcycle"].ToString()  : (object)System.DBNull.Value;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(bllingParam);

            OracleParameter freqLet = new OracleParameter("freqLettura",OracleType.VarChar);
            freqLet.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
            freqLet.Value= ((Session["freqLett"] != null )&&(Session["freqLett"].ToString().Length != 0)) ? Session["freqLett"].ToString()  : (object)System.DBNull.Value;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(freqLet);

            OracleParameter tipoElab = new OracleParameter("tipoElab",OracleType.VarChar);
            tipoElab.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
            tipoElab.Value= ((Session["tipoelab"] != null )&&(Session["tipoelab"].ToString().Length != 0)) ? Session["tipoelab"].ToString()  : (object)System.DBNull.Value;
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(tipoElab);

            OracleParameter startT = new OracleParameter("startTime",OracleType.DateTime);
            startT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
            startT.Value=Session["fStartDate"].ToString();
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(startT);

            OracleParameter stopT = new OracleParameter("stopTime",OracleType.DateTime);
            stopT.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
            stopT.Value=Session["fEndDate"].ToString();
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(stopT);

            OracleParameter schedPara = new OracleParameter("schedDate",OracleType.DateTime);
            schedPara.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
            schedPara.Value=Session["fSCHEDDATE"].ToString();
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(schedPara);

            OracleParameter seqVal = new OracleParameter("valoreSequence",OracleType.Number);
            seqVal.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;  
            seqVal.Value = Convert.ToInt32(sequenceVal);
            objCmd.Parameters.Add(seqVal);


            objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();


            OracleCommand cmdInsert = new OracleCommand("INSERT INTO batchrequest(uidbatchrequest,processnum,scheddate,starttime,stoptime,ratecode) " + 
            "  VALUES (:1,:2,:3,:4,:5,:6)", connection);
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("1", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(sequenceVal);
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("2", OracleType.Number).Value = Convert.ToInt32(Session["selectProcess"]);
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("3", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date1;
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("4", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date2;
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("5", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date3;
            cmdInsert.Parameters.Add("6", OracleType.VarChar, 64).Value = Session["tipoelab"].ToString();
            try
            {
                cmdInsert.ExecuteNonQuery();
                Label1.Text = "Richiesta inserita correttamente";
                connection.Close();
                return;
            }   
            catch(Exception ex){

              OracleCommand cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
              cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
              cmd.CommandText = "update batchrequest set scheddate = :1, starttime = :2, stoptime = :3, ratecode = 'S'  where scheddate = :keyValue";
              cmd.Parameters.Add("1", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date1;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("2", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date2;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("3", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date3;
              cmd.Parameters.Add("keyValue", OracleType.DateTime).Value = date1;

              try
              {
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                connection.Close();
              }   
              catch(Exception ee){
                    Label1.Text = "Richiesta inserita correttamente";
                    return;
              }

              Label1.Text = "Richiesta inserita correttamente";

              return;
            }
        }
```

i want highlight that when the procedure takes few time everything works well.
When takes long time last command : Insert or Update never stops on the db and i see the session in 
Inactive mode.

Answer (score 0):

If the query takes long, more then HTTP timeout that is set, you might be better off creating a database job, and starting the job from ASP.NET without waiting for it to finish.

Comment: but web.config says timeout: 90000000 it is possibile more then this time ?

Comment: Are you sure that the timeout is working? I doubt - that value represents in seconds the timeout. What is the longest time that the SQL takes to run? If in some cases it takes more then 5 minutes in my opinion do it as an SQL job. But this depends on your requirements.